# python udp server that listens to some specific ip addresses

Tags: python, server, udp, ip-address

Which address should I write, if I want that my server listens to 5-6 specific ip addresses?
I want my server to listen only to these addresses, and all of them, not just one.

```
import socket

ADDRESS = ('127.0.0.1', 5555)  /**here**

serverSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSock.bind(ADDRESS)
(data, addr) = serverSock.recvfrom(65535)
```

Comment: You have the choice between a global one (e.g. `0.0.0.0`) and a specific one (e.g. `1.2.3.4` or `127.0.0.1`). For multiple addresses you could listen in multiple threads. Don't expect any added security if all addresses are routeable.